# How to load cross-module resources/properties in Maven tests?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, maven-2, maven

I have a Maven maintained project with some modules. One module contains one XML file and one parsing class.

Second module depends on the first module. There is a class that calls the parsing class in the first module, but Maven cannot test the class in the second module. The test reports:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at java.util.Properties.loadFromXML(Properties.java:851)
 at foo.firstModule.Parser.<init>(Parser.java:92)
 at foo.secondModule.Program.<init>(Program.java:84)
```

In *Parser.java* (the first module), which uses `Properties` and `InputStream` to read/parse an XML file:

```
InputStream xmlStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("Data.xml");
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.loadFromXML(xmlStream);
```

The *Data.xml* is located in the first module's *resources/foo/firstModule* directory and tests OK in the first module.

It seems when testing the second module, Maven cannot correctly load the *Data.xml* from the first module .

I thought I can solve the problem by using **maven-dependency-plugin:unpack**. So I added these snippets to the second module's POM file:

```
<plugin>
 <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
 <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
 <version>2.1</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>data-copying</id>
      <phase>test-compile</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>unpack</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <artifactItems>
          <artifactItem>
            <groupId>foo</groupId>
            <artifactId>firstModule</artifactId>
            <type>jar</type>
            <includes>foo/firstModule/Data.xml</includes>
            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes</outputDirectory>
          </artifactItem>
        </artifactItems>
      </configuration>
    </execution>        
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

In this POM file I unpack the first module and copy the *Data.xml* into *classes/foo/firstModule/* directory and then run tests.

I can see that it is indeed copied into the right directory, but Maven test still cannot read it (`Properties.loadFromXML()` throws NPE).

I also tried a different output directory, such as *${project.build.directory}/resources* and *${project.build.directory}/test-classes*, but all in vain.

Environments: Maven 2.2.1, eclipse, m2eclipse

---- updated ----

I forget to mention, that the Program in the 2nd module, **extends** the Parser in the 1st module and in the Parser's constructor properties are loaded and parsed. In fact, Program is another Parser with further capabilities.

I think **Program extends Parser** may be causing the problem (i.e. `ClassLoader` issues).

If I disconnect the "inheritance" and initialize a new Parser inside the Program it works OK and the test passes!
I cannot, however, change the inheritance because of the way it's designed.

---- update with full code ----

This is the `Parser` in the first module :

```
package foo.firstModule;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.InvalidPropertiesFormatException;
import java.util.Properties;

public class Parser
{
  private Properties properties;
  
  public Parser()
  {
    InputStream xmlStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("Data.xml");
    properties = new Properties();
    try
    {
      properties.loadFromXML(xmlStream);
    }
    catch (InvalidPropertiesFormatException e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
  
  public Properties getProperties()
  {
    return properties;
  }
}
```

This is `Parser's` test case, which passes.

```
package foo.firstModule;

import junit.framework.TestCase;

public class ParserTest extends TestCase
{
  public void testParser()
  {
    Parser p = new Parser();
    assertEquals(64 , p.getProperties().size());
  }
}
```

This is `ParserExtend` in the *secondModule*, which extends `Parser` in the *firstModule*:

```
package foo.secondModule;

import java.util.Properties;

import foo.firstModule.Parser;

public class ParserExtend extends Parser
{
  private Properties properties;
  
  public ParserExtend()
  {
    this.properties = getProperties();
  }
  
  public int getSize()
  {
    return properties.size();
  }
}
```

This is `ParserExtend's` test case:

```
package foo.secondModule;

import junit.framework.TestCase;

public class ParserExtendTest extends TestCase
{
  public void testParserExtend()
  {
    ParserExtend pe = new ParserExtend();
    assertEquals(64 , pe.getSize());
  }
}
```

The above test case failed because **Properties.loadFromXML**(Properties.java:851) throws NPE.

However, if I don't extend `Parser` and just initialize a new `Parser`:

```
package foo.secondModule;

import java.util.Properties;

import foo.firstModule.Parser;

public class ParserInit
{
  private Properties properties;
  
  public ParserInit()
  {
    Parser p = new Parser();
    this.properties = p.getProperties();
  }
  
  public int getSize()
  {
    return properties.size();
  }
}
```

and test it using:

```
package foo.secondModule;

import junit.framework.TestCase;

public class ParserInitTest extends TestCase
{
  public void testParserInit()
  {
    ParserInit pi = new ParserInit();
    assertEquals(64 , pi.getSize());
  }
}
```

The test case passes!

This is my whole test scenario.
How can I pass the `ParserExtend's` test case?

Answer (score 0):

> It seems when testing the second module , maven cannot correctly load the Data.xml in the first module.

I created the exact same structure and I can't reproduce your problem. My `Program` class in the second module uses the `Parser` class from the first module which load properties from an XML file  **without** any problem. Tested under Eclipse and on the command line.

> I thought I can solve the problem by using `maven-dependency-plugin:unpack` to solve it.

Using `dependency:unpack` is definitely not a solution and if the first JAR contains `foo/firstModule/Data.xml`, using the `Parser` class from another module should just work. There must be something wrong somewhere else. If you can upload a representative test project, then please do so and I'll look at ti. Without a project allowing to reproduce, I'm afraid the best answer you'll get is "debug your code" :)

Comment: Hi , 
please try to make Program extends Parser , and in Parser's constructor , do the parsing job , and re-run the tests ... (this is how my architecture works...)

If it works for you , i have to check into my code more deeply...

Comment: @smallufo: Please update your question to show your code so that I can reproduce.

Comment: Thank you , I've added further comments in the tail of the question.

Comment: @smallufo I'm sorry but I'm not going to try to guess how your code works (and I'm not going to ask you a third time to show some code allowing to reproduce).

Comment: Thanks for replying . I've appended my full code with test cases... Hope it helps...

Answer (score 0):

I agree, it sounds like classloader issues.

If you always intend on having Data.xml in /foo/firstModule/Data.xml location, give this a try in `foo.firstModule.Parser`:

`InputStream xmlStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/foo/firstModule/Data.xml");`

Or, if you're explicitly wanting the behavior of finding a "local" Data.xml should firstModule be reused elsewhere (e.g. secondModule or thirdModule has its own Data.xml), try this:

`InputStream xmlStream = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("Data.xml");`

Comment: Hi , thanks for replying.
If I change to Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("Data.xml");

The ParserTest will fail too.